# Selected item from Datagridview to Show in ComboBox

Tags: sql, vb.net, drop-down-menu, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to get a selected item from datagridview to show in a combobox.

I have done

```
ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
```

However, I need it to display two fields in the combobox from the datagrid. Is there a way to do the above with a SQL query? Because I need to concat a query to display in the combobox because right now it's only displaying one field that I need. Thank you :-)

Comment: Want to add a little more code or explanation?  You want 2 different values from 2 different columns in a grid to show up in the dropdown?

Comment: Show how you are filling the combobox. There are hundreds of ways to do this but to tailor something that fits your needs requires more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing something like this.

```
        ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).FormattedValue + " " + DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(1).FormattedValue
```

or

```
        ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).FormattedValue + " " + _
                         DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(1).FormattedValue
```

However if your drop down list box has an ID in the value you and you have it in the Grid, you set the

```
ComboBox1.Value = DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.SelectedIndex].Cells["HiddenIdRow"].Text.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ComboBox.Add('cellValue1 + 'cellvalue2')

ComboBox1.Text will just set the original text, but will not create a list of data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via SQL query, `cmd` should look like this:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName FROM Table
```

If this doesn't help you, it would be useful to know the current query you are using and the purpose of the combobox